# Great Expectation and Spark : get full list of include_unexpected_rows

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, great-expectations

I'm currently testing my datasets and so far so good, unfortunately i'm unable to get rows that don't match my expectations.
I'm using a SparkDFExecutionEngine Execution Engine

For exemple :

```
validator.expect_column_values_to_not_be_null(column="EmailAddress",result_format="COMPLETE",include_unexpected_rows=True)
```

does not yield the rest of the row when the email address is null, which means I have to manually read the dataset again by filtering on null.
Is there a good way with GE to get the row when the expectation is not matched ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, specifically with the `expect_column_values_to_not_be_null` Expectation. If you [file a Github Issue](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=), the team should be able to resolve it. Then this should work like all of the other Expectations.